# Woocommerce prevent users from changing their email address

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is there any way i can prevent users from changing their email address from account settings page?
Since WC doesn't even confirm email address before updating it, it kinda raise a security threat for my WC Marketplace.

I've custom codded plugin where users can change their email address but they must then verify it. But WC doesn't seem to have any hook or filter to remove email change from their backend.

PS: i know i can remove it by simply editing edit-account template but users can easily add html field by inspect element and change their email address.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11717/prevent-users-from-changing-their-email-address