# Prevent the customer (user) from changing the email in Account details on the My-Account page or any other part of the wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, account

When a customer or user registers on the site, he can easily change and save his email in the Account details section, and that's it!

How can I prevent the change of the user's email in all parts and sections of the site and only the site administrator can change the user's email, not any other user or person, even the user himself?

*I don't want to just hide this option by CSS or in the front end, but I want it to be completely removed or unusable so that the end user who has mastered CSS and... cannot change the email with tricks.*

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Bhautik, From the way in the comments of this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44321446/woocommerce-prevent-users-from-changing-their-email-address
It was said that I used it, but it didn't work at all!

Comment: Then it's required further debug,

Comment: @Bhautik I'm looking for a way that can be done only through function.php and PHP code and I don't want to edit my WooCommerce or WordPress files.
Most of the methods are to edit the original files, which I don't mean at all!

Comment: I didn't say that you need to edit your WooCommerce or WordPress files. I am saying if you tried the solution that you found and it's not working then it's required further debugging on your site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is prohibited by most countries' legislation for internet websites, and more strongly on e-commerce business (EU countries are even stricter and have a hard position on the subject). Customer have the right to access/change/remove their data.

To remove the billing email address from My Account Edit Address and Checkout when the billing email already exists, use the following:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'disable_billing_email_changes' );
function disable_billing_email_changes( $billing_fields ) {
    $billing_email = WC()->customer->get_billing_email();

    // If email ealready xists
    if ($billing_email) {
        unset($billing_fields["billing_email"]); // Remove billing email field
    }
    return $billing_fields;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

To remove or hide the user email (when it already exists), from My Account Account details section, you will have to [override via your child theme](https://woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/), the template file [`myaccount/form-edit-account.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/form-edit-account.php).

You will replace:

```
    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="account_email"><?php esc_html_e( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="email" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--email input-text" name="account_email" id="account_email" autocomplete="email" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->user_email ); ?>" />
    </p>
```

with the following:

```
<?php $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( ! $current_user->user_email ) : ?>
    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="account_email"><?php esc_html_e( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="email" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--email input-text" name="account_email" id="account_email" autocomplete="email" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->user_email ); ?>" />
    </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Excellent and thank you very much
I have just one question, when in (My Account Account details section) from the command $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( ! $current_user->user_email ) we use. Can this section be displayed by users who are not even logged into their own account, or can it only be displayed by member users who are logged into their own panel?

Comment: And is there a solution to use function.php without having to edit the form-edit-account.php file (or a copy of this file in the theme)? I am only asking for my knowledge and my problem is solved with your answer.

Comment: All the My account section is only visible to logged in customers. using `if ( ! $current_user->user_email ) : ?>`is just a way to remove the email from customer view, and keeping the field in the template. As The field is hard coded in the template, there is no other way to overwrite it via your child theme.